# Iterate over a process' maps file

Tags: c, parsing, linux

The following logic provides iteration over `/proc/<PID>/maps` for a Linux process.  What I'm primarily (though not solely) interested in for this review is whether or not I've made any invalid assumptions about the layout of the `maps` file.

iterate_map.h

```c
#ifndef REAP_ITERATE_MAP_H
#define REAP_ITERATE_MAP_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define REAP_PATH_SIZE 256

enum reapRetValue {
    REAP_RET_OK,             /**< The function was successful.*/
    REAP_RET_DONE,           /**< The iteration is finished.*/
    REAP_RET_BAD_USAGE,      /**< A funciton was called with invalid arguments.*/
    REAP_RET_OUT_OF_MEMORY,  /**< A memory allocation failed.*/
    REAP_RET_NO_PERMISSION,  /**< No permission to access a requested resource.*/
    REAP_RET_NOT_FOUND,      /**< A requested resource was not found.*/
    REAP_RET_TOO_MANY_LINKS, /**< Too many symbolic links encountered.*/
    REAP_RET_FILE_READ,      /**< Failed to read from a file.*/
    REAP_RET_OTHER,          /**< Catch-all error.*/
};

/**
 * @brief Iterates over all line in a /proc/<PID>/maps file.
 *
 * @note User code should not access the iterator's fields.
 */
typedef struct reapMapIterator {
    FILE *file;
} reapMapIterator;

/**
 * @brief Result generated by a reapMapIterator.
 */
typedef struct reapMapResult {
    unsigned long start;             /**< The start of the memory section.*/
    unsigned long end;               /**< The end of the memory section.*/
    unsigned int offset;             /**< The offset of the memory section in the referent file.*/
    int permissions;                 /**< The permissions of the memory section.*/
    dev_t device;                    /**< The device number of the referent file.*/
    ino_t inode;                     /**< The inode of the referent file.*/
    char name[REAP_PATH_SIZE];       /**< The name of the referent file.*/
} reapMapResult;

/**
 * @brief Initializes an iterator.
 *
 * @param pid       The PID.
 * @param iterator  A pointer to the iterator.
 *
 * @return          REAP_RET_OK if successful and an error code otherwise.
 */
int
reapMapIteratorInit(pid_t pid, reapMapIterator *iterator);

/**
 * @brief Closes an iterator.
 *
 * @param iterator A pointer to the iterator.
 */
void
reapMapIteratorClose(reapMapIterator *iterator);

/**
 * @brief Gets the next result.
 *
 * @param iterator      A pointer to the iterator.
 * @param[out] result   A pointer to the result to be populated.
 *
 * @return              REAP_RET_OK if a result was found, REAP_RET_DONE if the iteration is finished, and an
 * error code otherwise.
 */
int
reapMapIteratorNext(const reapMapIterator *iterator, reapMapResult *result);

#endif  // REAP_ITERATE_MAP_H
```

iterate_map.c

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/sysmacros.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <reap/iterate_map.h>

static int
translateErrno(void)
{
    switch (errno) {
    case EINVAL: return REAP_RET_BAD_USAGE;
    case EACCES: return REAP_RET_NO_PERMISSION;
    case ELOOP: return REAP_RET_TOO_MANY_LINKS;
    case ENOENT:
    case ENOTDIR:
    case EIO: return REAP_RET_FILE_READ;
    case ENOMEM: return REAP_RET_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    default: return REAP_RET_OTHER;
    }
}

int
reapMapIteratorInit(pid_t pid, reapMapIterator *iterator)
{
    char buffer[100];

    if (pid <= 0 || !iterator) {
        return REAP_RET_BAD_USAGE;
    }

    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "/proc/%li/maps", (long)pid);
    iterator->file = fopen(buffer, "r");
    if (!iterator->file) {
        return translateErrno();
    }

    return REAP_RET_OK;
}

void
reapMapIteratorClose(reapMapIterator *iterator)
{
    if (iterator && iterator->file) {
        fclose(iterator->file);
        iterator->file = NULL;
    }
}

int
reapMapIteratorNext(const reapMapIterator *iterator, reapMapResult *result)
{
    int num_matches;
    unsigned int major, minor;
    unsigned long inode;
    char r, w, x;
    char line[256];

    if (!iterator || !iterator->file || !result) {
        return REAP_RET_BAD_USAGE;
    }

    if (!fgets(line, sizeof(line), iterator->file)) {
        if (ferror(iterator->file)) {
            return REAP_RET_FILE_READ;
        }
        else {
            return REAP_RET_DONE;
        }
    }
    num_matches = sscanf(line, "%lx-%lx %c%c%c%*c %x %x:%x %lu %s", &result->start, &result->end, &r, &w, &x,
                         &result->offset, &major, &minor, &inode, result->name);
    if (num_matches < 9) {
        return REAP_RET_OTHER;
    }

    if (num_matches == 9) {
        result->name[0] = '\0';
    }

    result->permissions = 0;
    if (r == 'r') {
        result->permissions |= PROT_READ;
    }
    if (w == 'w') {
        result->permissions |= PROT_WRITE;
    }
    if (x == 'x') {
        result->permissions |= PROT_EXEC;
    }

    result->device = makedev(major, minor);
    result->inode = inode;

    return REAP_RET_OK;
}
```

Comment: Why 256 in `#define REAP_PATH_SIZE 256`?  256 deserves some explanation.

Comment: Are you asking why it's a power of 2 or why I'm not using the already-defined `PATH_SIZE`?

Comment: Daniel Walker, OK, why power of 2, why not `PATH_SIZE`, why undocumented?

Comment: I didn't want to make the structure take up too much space. Consider if I wanted to form an array or linked list of all of a process' map entries. That's a lot of memory to allocate when, in all likelihood, none of the paths will be anywhere near `PATH_SIZE` in length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If user code is not supposed to access the innards of a `reapMapIterator`, it's best to make it an incomplete type in the header, and define it only in the implementation.  A small change is needed to the interface, so that `reapMapIteratorInit()` returns an allocated `reapMapIterator` and `reapMapIteratorClose()` also frees the memory.

I don't like the translation of `errno` values to `reapRetValue` - the former are much more usable, given that `strerror()` already exists to provide translated user messages.

Comment: Perhaps I could return `-1*errno` instead so that the caller knows when an `errno` value is being returned.